# Как извлечь дробную часть из числа на sql в oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql

Как извлечь дробную часть из числа на sql в oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто:
`select mod(12.345, 1) from dual;`
выдаст 0.345

Answer (score 0):

Не факт что на `Oracle` пойдёт, но суть такая:

```
select abs( num - cast( num as bigint ) ) as num from ( select num = -123.123 ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
x number(12,4) := 12.345;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(x - floor(x));
exception
when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ' ' || sqlerrm);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция **mod()** — http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions101.htm

Answer (score -1):

дробную часть можно извлечь, например, так:

```
x - trunc(x)
```

Comment: привёл ответ к нормальному виду. о правильности ответа представления не имею.

Comment: ответ был приведён к тупому виду, такому же как система вынуждающая писать 30 символов там, где достаточно 12